# Why is this MySQL query not working?

Tags: mysql

What's wrong with these two queries?

```
SELECT (DATE_ADD('2008-11-31',INTERVAL 365 DAY) + INTERVAL 0 DAY) as occursOn
Result:
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [occursOn] => 
        )

)
```

And:

```
SELECT (DATE_ADD('2008-11-31',INTERVAL 730 DAY) + INTERVAL 0 DAY) as occursOn
Result:
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [occursOn] => 
        )

)
```

As you can see, the returned value of `occursOn` is blank each time.

These queries are being generated dynamically, therefore the second `+INTERVAL 0 DAY` is needed and can't be eliminated.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

2008-11-31 not valid date only 30 days in 11th month (November)

Answer (score 10):

Probably because `November` has `30` days?